# Easier way with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this function that I am using to create a new category on a forum board using jQuery's `append()` function. It's working fine but I would like to know if there is an easier and/or quicker way I could be doing this.

Here is my code:

```
function createCategory() {
    $(parent).prepend('<div id="CategoryGroup-favourites" class="CategoryGroup"></div>');
    $('#CategoryGroup-favourites').append('<h2 class="H">Favourites</h2>')
                                .append('<div class="DataTableWrap"></div>');
    $('#CategoryGroup-favourites .DataTableWrap').append('<table class="DataTable CategoryTable"></table>');
    $('#CategoryGroup-favourites table').append('<thead></thead>')
                                        .append('<tbody></tbody>');
    $('#CategoryGroup-favourites thead').append('<tr></tr>');
    $('#CategoryGroup-favourites tr').append('<td class="CategoryName"></td>')
                                .append('<td class="BigCount CountDiscussions"></td>')
                                .append('<td class="BigCount CountComments"></td>')
                                .append('<td class="BlockColumn LatestPost"></td>');
}
```

Any help to get this simpler would be nice.

Comment: you can use multi line string in javascript with a forward slash at the end of each line. If that's what you mean.

Comment: @Bryan No that's not needed. My question leans more towards the jQuery side of things as I gather there are methods to cut this code down. Hence why I didn't tag Javascript.

Comment: it just doesn't make sense to create a new element and then append to it, why not create the markup all at once and prepend it to `parent` ?

Comment: @Bryan I don't own the page. It's a forum board I frequent and I'm making things easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

What @Bryan was getting at in his comments is that since you are adding arbitrary HTML with jQuery anyway, why not do it all at once? You are repeatedly adding an element, then selecting it, adding to it, then selecting *that* addition, and so on. Instead, simply construct your new `div` in its entirety, and then prepend that:

```
function createCategory() {
  var newDivHtml = '\
  <div id="CategoryGroup-favourites" class="CategoryGroup">\
    <h2 class="H">Favourites</h2>\
    <div class="DataTableWrap">\
      <table class="DataTable CategoryTable">\
        <thead>\
          <tr>\
            <td class="CategoryName"></td>\
            <td class="BigCount CountDiscussions"></td>\
            <td class="BigCount CountComments"></td>\
            <td class="BlockColumn LatestPost"></td>\
          </tr>\
        </thead>\
        <tbody></tbody>\
      </table>\
    </div>\
  </div>';

  $(parent).prepend(newDivHtml);
}
```

Here's a [sample jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/munderwood/bBv67/) with the two version of `createCategory`. If you inspect the elements after running it, they should be identical.

Answer (score 0):

jquery create elements on the fly

```
$("<div/>",{
    "class" : "someelement",
    // .. you can go on and add properties
    "css" : {
        "color" : "red"
    },
    "click" : function(){
        alert("you just clicked me!!");
    },
    "data" : {
       "foo" : "bar"
    }
}).appendTo("#container");
```

create div and set id ,class,css ,event on the fly
This is the way to go if youre setting multiple properties. Much cleaner than passing in a long string.